# Query is from python. i have an input of sentence. I want to split the sentence into each alphabet. Then I want to use following function. Suggest

Tags: python, string, split

In the following code, when I type Sam as input, it shows correct result as 'String contains letter s'
But when I type Sam Aron, it shows two messages first for Sam as String contains letter s  and below that as String does not contain letter s for word Aron, seperated by space in the given input.
How can I make it treat the full input as single string and give single message for full sentence such as string contains letter S (for 'Sam Aron')

```
def check_string():
    a = input()
    b = a.split()
    for i in b:
        if 's' in i or 'S' in i:
            print('String contains letter s')
        else:
            print('String does not contain letter s')
check_string()
```

Comment: If you want to treat the input as a single string, can you say more about the purpose of the line `b = a.split()` ?

Comment: Don't split the input? `if 's' in a.lower()`

Comment: It is giving multiple messages for every letter when i remove split

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check for the letter 'S' in the entire string, then don't split the input by spaces.

```py
def check_string():
    a = input()
    for i in a:
        if 's' == i or 'S' == i:
            print('String contains letter s')
        else:
            print('String does not contain letter s')
check_string()
```

However there is a better way to do it

```py
def check_string():
    a = input().lower()
    if 's' in a:
        print('String contains letter s')
    else:
        print('String does not contain letter s')
```

Comment: Did you try the first code?

Comment: @Guy i missed the equality part in the first code piece :) however the second one is the actual solution. anyway, edited

Comment: Thanks @AhmedAshraf, the better way worked